# table in dv which cab scroll in x and y with left heading column fix when scrolls in x

Tags: css, css-float

I want the height of this table fixed(http://jsfiddle.net/emn13/YMvk9/) so that when more rows are added to it , i can scroll in y-axis and the left fixed row column should scroll as each row moves up.

```
<div><table>
        <tr><td class="headcol">1</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">2</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">3</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">4</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">5</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">6</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">7</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">8</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="headcol">9</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
</table></div>
```

CSS as below

```
body { font:16px Calibri;}
table { border-collapse:separate; border-top: 3px solid grey; height:100px;}
td {
    margin:0;
    border:3px solid grey; 
    border-top-width:0px; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div { 
    width: 600px; 
    overflow-x:scroll;  
    margin-left:5em; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
.headcol {
    position:absolute; 
    width:5em; 
    left:0;
    top:auto;
    border-right: 0px none black; 
    border-top-width:3px; /*only relevant for first row*/
    margin-top:-3px; /*compensate for top border*/
}
.headcol:before {content: 'Row ';}
.long { background:yellow; letter-spacing:1em; }
```

The above code is from answer to another question which solves my problem half by keeping left Row headings fixed, but i want to scroll in y-axis as well

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue. The jsFiddle shows it is y-axis scrollable.

Comment: try adding more rows to it an you will see it does't work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the problem, but I don't think there's a single-table solution to this, and I don't think you can achieve the effect without using JavaScript.

Here's a two-table JavaScript solution.  I put each table in a `div`.  When you scroll the second table, the first will be scrolled the same amount.

```js
var c1= document.getElementById('container1');
var c2= document.getElementById('container2');
c2.onscroll= function() {
  c1.scrollTop= c2.scrollTop;
}
```

```css
.long {
  background:yellow;
  letter-spacing:1em;
}

table {
  border-spacing:0px;
}

#container1 {
  float: left;
  width: 5em;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#container2 {
  width: 30em;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#container1 tr, #container2 tr {
  height: 1.5em;
}

#container1 table, #container2 table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">
 <table>
  <tr><td>Row 1
  <tr><td>Row 2
  <tr><td>Row 3
  <tr><td>Row 4
  <tr><td>Row 5
  <tr><td>Row 6
  <tr><td>Row 7
  <tr><td>Row 8
  <tr><td>Row 9
  <tr><td>Row 10
  <tr><td>Row 11
  <tr><td>Row 12
  <tr><td>Row 13
  <tr><td>Row 14
  <tr><td>Row 15
  <tr><td>Row 16
  <tr><td>Row 17
  <tr><td>Row 18
  <tr><td>Row 19
  <tr><td>Row 20
 </table>
</div>
<div id="container2">
 <table>
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
  <tr><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, even i think single table cannot handle this situation , so i will accept your answer with js solution